# What is the correct approach for a user with low reputation to respond to a comment they can't comment on although the comment addresses their answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, reputation, meta

I am wondering about the scenario in which a low-reputation user (myself) answers a question, and then someone else posts a comment relevant to my answer to someone else's mostly-identical or similar answer.

To be more specific: if I post an answer and someone else posts a similar answer, but a commentor chooses to comment on the other user's answer and I lack the reputation to  *also* comment, what is the appropriate way to respond to that comment?

1. Just comment on my own answer as though the other user's comment was posted there?
2. Update my answer and leave it at that?
3. Other? ...

I would think solution 2 would not always work. For example, in scenarios in which the response to the comment is lengthy/detailed or not directly relevant to the original answer and therefore confusing or distracting for people in the future.

Thoughts?

Comment: 3.Other.You should earn that privileges or leave it or you can discuss here about the problem.

Comment: @Shaiful Islam. That's just dumb. There are plenty of people new to the site or that don't have the time to gain reputation but come across something they might be a pro at. Stack overflow reputation should never trump real-world experience/knowledge.

Comment: an experienced/ a knowledgeable person can earn that reputation easily.And you should [read more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124811/why-cant-we-comment-on-questions-when-new-user)

Comment: If you mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31459716/3001761) my suggestion would be to answer better questions - trivial stuff like that you'll often end up with half a dozen more-or-less identical answers in the first five minutes with nothing to choose between them anyway. And (as in that case) the OP just picks the first one that does exactly what they need, whether it's well explained or not, and walks away.

Comment: To expand on the post jonrsharpe found, you also answered a question by a user who can't upvote yet (< 15 reputation).  So they can only award a single person reputation with the accept.  They can't upvote any other also helpful answers.

Comment: Sorry that you think the guidelines here are *dumb*, but you have three choices available: 1) follow them, 2) go somewhere else, or 3)  post a feature request here at Meta requesting the guidelines be changed and follow the guidelines until that happens. The guidelines (including those requiring a certain amount of reputation in order to have the privilege to comment) are in place for a reason. In the case of comments, it prevents drive by comments, spam, and tons of noise and clutter by new users who don't understand how they're intended to be used.

Comment: I'm curious what you want to comment on there. That could change the answer to your question.

Comment: @codeMagic I image it would be a response to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459716/how-to-combine-specific-letters-and-numbers-from-different-cells-in-excel#comment50886765_31459815)

Comment: @TinyGiant maybe. But I'm not sure why. The question got an accepted answer so the OP now knows what to do to get the desired result

Comment: @codeMagic I didn't say it was rational.

Comment: @theforestecologist You need to find better questions to answer. Questions like these are likely to be closed (this one contains no code) at the time of writing there are three out of a necessary five close votes on that question. It is unlikely that these questions will net you any rep. Please look for quality questions before answering.

Comment: You're all missing the point. Yes that one post is a straw man example. But I'm sure this issue arises with better questions. I'm just askin what the proper approach is.

Comment: The proper approach is really simple, wait for the other user to contact you, if you think you have an important point to add then add a comment on your own post... and wait. This will no longer be an issue once you've reached 50 rep, so best suggestion is get back out there and keep answering questions. :) One of those things that is the lesser of two evils, and only a hindrance for a short period of time. I don't imagine that you plan on having less than 50 rep for long, do you?

Comment: @Ken White, I don't think the guidelines are dumb. I think the pompous approach that many take on this website is unnecessary and dumb. The point of this site is to *help* people. It's not to gather reputation to brag to your friends or to use it as a resume builder -- real world people will not jump on hiring someone that can't interact with others *no matter*  how good they are at what they do! I think many here need to re-visit the purpose of answering questions for others in the first place.

Comment: @theforestecologist Please, please, please don't start with the name-calling. It will never get you anywhere here. If you want honest (while somewhat intentionally silly) discussion then you should not follow in the steps of those who came before you. If you want a flame war then by all means resort to name-calling, but it doesn't usually work.

Comment: @Tiny Giant. There was no name calling. I just htink that many of the *interactions* that I and many of my peers have received on this site can be classified as pompous, and to me that's just missing the point of a website dedicated to helping others.

Comment: You are definitely misunderstanding the purpose of this site. It is mostly to build a repository of the most useful information for programmers everywhere. Or something along those lines. When it really comes down to it, it is not really about answering the question for the OP, but providing Good Answers to Good Questions which are useful to future viewers. The OP getting their issue solved is just a side-effect. Someone will probably post a link to the correct phrasing of this comment but that is the general idea.

Comment: I think things are getting a little out of hand. @theforestecologist you aren't the first new user to think that users on the site can be pompous, jerks, or whatever. The privilege limits may seem that way to some but they are actually there for very good reasons. Some of these have been mentioned in previous comments and all have been discussed on meta if you want to search and see *why* these things exist. But, simply, if the question wasn't aimed at you then get the necessary rep to comment. It really can only take a few good answers.

Comment: If the comment mentioned something that you can address in an edit to your answer then do so

Comment: You're absolutely wrong about the purpose of this site. It's intent is to help **everyone**, not **individuals**. This was never intended to be a "please be my personal consultant or programmer* site. It's designed to be a collection of knowledge related to programming that will help many people. If you happen to get a solution to your personal issue here, that's a side benefit. Referring to people who donate their time for free to share knowledge as *pompous and dumb* is in fact name calling. Insulting people (individually or en masse) is not acceptable behavior here.

Comment: As a direct response to your (poorly stated) question of "Thoughts?", my thoughts are that new users should be expected to follow the guidelines, and earn privileges just like everyone else. New users should not expect or be given any more consideration than experienced users. Everyone here should be held to the same guidelines and quality standards. I also think that if someone can't put the time in to earn the extremely low amount of reputation needed in order to post comments, they probably don't have a lot to say that will add value to this site.

Comment: And what a massive collection of knowledge it is! For potato sake, it's just a matter of asking Google: issue X, language Y, site:stackoverflow.com. Bang! Solutions galore!! Try doing the same in the 90's :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wait until you can comment.

It's great that you're actively contributing to Stack Overflow and that you're clearly trying to give good answers. Please keep doing that and you'll soon forget this short episode in which commenting was blocked.

This raised bar for commenting has [very good reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/168269). Without it, the site would be swamped with spam or comments from people still thinking in the forum paradigm. Q&A is quite different and it usually takes a little experience to appreciate this difference. Of course there will always be people (like you) who understand the difference right away, but that's the way it is, the good suffer with the bad.

In this specific case you might update your answer if the comment clearly shows a way to be more helpful, but don't try to respond to the comment itself in this way. That will make things very messy.

Just like any of us, you are bound to see many more situations in which the best thing to do is: **shrug, leave it, move on**.