# What rate of suggested edits is considered flooding the queue?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A new user finds that the majority of questions on the front page are too unclear to be answered well. It takes 50 reputation to begin to help the asker. How long should a new user expect it to take to suggest 25 edits without wasting the time of suggested edit reviewers? Or what rate of editing will cause moderators to impose an edit ban?

[An answer by Gert Arnold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299579/2738262) recommends that a new user who finds an unclear question "shrug, leave it, move on." Answers to other related questions tend to echo the sentiment: "wait until you do have the reputation." But because reputation in Stack Overflow does *not* accumulate over time on a new user's idle account, a new user will have to do something to earn this reputation.

[An answer by ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258612/2738262) recommends that new users try one of these:

> - 5 upvotes on answers
> - 10 upvotes on questions
> - 25 edit suggestions accepted

The "5 upvotes on answers" is difficult for a new user to achieve. The top-scored questions on the "unanswered" tab (or "need answers" in new UI) remain on that tab because they have stumped other users, and they'd be even more likely to stump a new user. So the user will be left trying to find those few front-page questions that neither require clarification nor already have an answer by [someone faster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). The difficulty of finding questions that are answerable yet unanswered leads to the phenomenon of newbies answering questions that aren't the greatest.

The "10 upvotes on questions" is likewise difficult. A new user may not have a strong sense of what's on-topic, as the description in the Help Center's on-topic page is typically far from the whole story. So a user might follow Music moderator NReilingh's advice to [answer before asking](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/333/13519), which brings us back to the previous paragraph.

This leaves 25 suggested edits. I already know [just removing "Thanks" without other changes and editing too fast are discouraged](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14558/232993). But how fast is too fast? I know [131 edits in four hours are too many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258327/2738262), but is there a rate that a new user should shoot for in order to eliminate the risk of an edit ban?

"based on actual problems that **you** face": I plan to introduce new users to Stack Overflow, and I feel that they are likely to get hung up on not only the 50 rep requirement to participate in clarification but also the 5 rep requirement even to ask how to proceed. I'm currently suggesting that they practice their Markdown by editing five posts over a couple days to get up to 11 (to be able to cite more than two sources) and reminding them to "fix *all* the problems with the post".

Comment: Semi-related: [mentors for new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254205/opt-in-mentor-privilege-at-7-5k)

Comment: The main problem in wanting to gain rep "fast and easy" by editing is that it could be considered *too easy*. I think your reminder should appear bold and underlined, so to not waste their own time as well as the time (and quotum) of the review-reviewers.

Comment: 2 accepted answers with a single upvote each provides 50 rep. That is relatively simple to achieve (depending on the tags), you only have to find two questions out of the flood of unclear questions to get that.

Comment: My very first answer was 23 minutes after the question was posted and the 2nd answer on the question.  It earned me 55 reputation, enough to comment.  It wasn't a great answer or question, but it was an acceptable one.  It solved the original poster's problem.  Do you have evidence that this is not a feasible way to earn 50 reputation today?  Admittedly, I did understand the tag in question prior to posting an answer: if the problem is "lack of expertise makes earning reputation more difficult", is that a problem?

Comment: @Yakk Then perhaps I should ask another question about how to write a great second answer as your first answer.

Answer (score 16):

TL;DR I consider suggested edits "flooding the queue" when I am annoyed to see the same user's suggestions during a review session.

---

I do a lot of my reviews of suggested edits in blocks of 5-10.  This means I notice when users are spamming lots of suggestions in a short time period.  If they are able to put in so many suggestions that I see their name appear 4 times in my block of reviews, it's a good indication their edits are really minor and/or incomplete.  These kinds of suggestions often address only one aspect of the post.  Examples include questionable "improved formatting" edits or only fixing tags.  Seeing a bunch of these half-baked suggestions from the same user annoys me quite a bit and makes lean towards rejecting the edits as "no improvement whatsoever."

Sometimes I see repeated good edits from the same user, but these are much rarer occurrences.  Good suggestions take more time on average to fix (almost) everything with a post.  That makes it less likely to see more than a couple of suggestions from the same user making these thorough suggestions.  Even if I do see 4 consecutive good suggestions from the same user, I'm happy to approve their complete and helpful suggestions.

These aren't precise metrics by any means, but they are the standards by which I define "serial minor edit suggestions."

Comment: You had me at `TL;DR;`

Comment: Keyword being "annoyed". If you're pleased with someone's edits - regardless of whether they're actually useful edits - you'll pass them all.

Answer (score 2):

> flood (fləd/)
>   verb gerund or present participle: flooding
>
> 1. cover or submerge (a place or area) with water.
>      synonyms:   inundate, swamp, deluge, immerse, submerge, drown, engulf
> 2. arrive in overwhelming amounts or quantities.
>      "congratulatory messages flooded in"

For me *"flooding the suggested edit review queue"* means: ***crap*** arrive in overwhelming amounts or quantities. I do not care which user(s) are doing edits as long as I would have suggested them myself. Remember, blame the sin, not the sinner.

How I discover them? If I had to reject the same kind of edits in a short while, I check who made them, then go through their recent activity and reject/approve as appropiated.